# C - Using FFTW, fftw_plan_dft_1d to do convolution

Tags: c, convolution, fftw

**Solved** : **Turns out my code was mostly right, but I had forgotten that convolution flips the kernel from the search, so I was misusing the function.  See my answer for my current code and provided an analogous, non-FFT function**

It seems that there have been a few people who have asked a question of how to actually do a 1D convolution, specifically with FFTW.   I'm trying to do it with FFTW3, with absolutely no success.

Others have asked similar questions but post unrelated languages responses as "solutions."  If I get this solved, I will post an actual C solution!

See: [How to multiply 2 fftw_complex arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802180/how-to-multiply-2-fftw-complex-arrays) and [Calculating convolution of two functions using FFT (FFTW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178080/calculating-convolution-of-two-functions-using-fft-fftw)

```
void Convolve( double * data, double * kernel, double * convout, int size )
{
    int i;

    size *= 2;  //Create zero-padded arrays.

    fftw_complex in_sequence[size], freq_sequence[size];
    fftw_complex in_data[size], freq_data[size];
    fftw_complex rev_data[size], time_data[size];
    fftw_plan p1 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, in_sequence, freq_sequence, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan p2 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, in_data, freq_data,         FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan rev = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, rev_data, time_data,       FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    //Load our real data into the complex arrays.
    for( i = 0; i < size/2; i++ )
    {
        in_sequence[i][0] = kernel[i];
        in_sequence[i][1] = 0;

        in_data[i][0] = data[i];
        in_data[i][1] = 0;
    }
    for( ; i < size; i++ )
    {
        in_sequence[i][0] = in_sequence[i][1] = 0;
        in_data[i][0] = in_data[i][1] = 0;
    }

    fftw_execute(p1);
    fftw_execute(p2);

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        double realD = freq_data[i][0];
        double imagD = freq_data[i][1];
        double realS = freq_sequence[i][0];
        double imagS = freq_sequence[i][1];
        rev_data[i][0] = (realD * realS - imagD * imagS)/size;
        rev_data[i][1] = (realD * imagS + imagD * realS)/size;
    }

    fftw_execute(rev);

    for( i = 0; i < size/2; i++ )
    {
        convout[i] = (time_data[i][0]*time_data[i][0]-time_data[i][1]*time_data[i][1]);
    }
}
```

The output from this code has numbers, but these numbers do not correspond to a convolution of the signals.

Comment: Do you want [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) ? If not then you have to pad.

Comment: Nope.  I already double the size of the input, then zero-pad that second half of the double-size array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as stated in the question update, my issue was that the kernel you are convolving with is flipped when performing convolution.   I have updated code here and a copy of that function that uses regular C.  I've verified the functions produce similar output.

```
void Convolve( double * data, double * kernel, double * convout, int size )
{
    int a, b;
    for( a = 0; a < size*2; a++ )
    {
        double cvo = 0;
        for( b = 0; b < size; b++ )
        {
            if( a-b<0 ) continue;
            cvo += data[b] * kernel[a-b];
        }
        convout[a] = cvo;
    }
}

//Convout's array size must be 2*size.
void FFTConvolve( double * data, double * kernel, double * convout, int size )
{
    struct timeval tvs, tve;
    int i;

    //Pad the 2nd half of the data with 0's.
    size *= 2;

    fftw_complex in_sequence[size], freq_sequence[size];
    fftw_complex in_data[size], freq_data[size];
    fftw_complex rev_data[size], time_data[size];
    fftw_plan p1 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, in_sequence, freq_sequence, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan p2 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, in_data, freq_data,         FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan rev = fftw_plan_dft_1d(size, rev_data, time_data,       FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    for( i = 0; i < size/2; i++ )
    {
        in_sequence[i][0] = kernel[i];
        in_sequence[i][1] = 0;

        in_data[i][0] = data[i];
        in_data[i][1] = 0;
    }
    for( ; i < size; i++ )
    {
        in_sequence[i][0] = in_sequence[i][1] = 0;
        in_data[i][0] = in_data[i][1] = 0;
    }

    fftw_execute(p1);
    fftw_execute(p2);

    double mux = 1.0/size;

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        double realD = freq_data[i][0];
        double imagD = freq_data[i][1];
        double realS = freq_sequence[i][0];
        double imagS = freq_sequence[i][1];
        rev_data[i][0] = (realD * realS - imagD * imagS)*mux;
        rev_data[i][1] = (realD * imagS + imagD * realS)*mux;
    }

    fftw_execute(rev);

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        convout[i] = time_data[i][0]; // The i term should be non-existent.
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, using a "non-flipped" kernel actually gives you cross-correlation rather than convolution, which is another useful application.

Comment: Oh my! I will have tor read about it.  Cross-correlation "sounds" like something I'm interested in for this application!

Comment: Yes,  correlation and convolution are almost the same mathematically, except the time (or equivalent) axis for one of the inputs is reversed in one relative to the other.